# Updating a sliced list

Tags: python, list

I thought I understood Python slicing operations, but when I tried to update a sliced list, I got confused:

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> foo[:1] = ['one'] # OK, foo updated
>>> foo
['one', 2, 3, 4] 
>>> foo[:][1] = 'two' # why foo not updated?
>>> foo
['one', 2, 3, 4] 
>>> foo[:][2:] = ['three', 'four'] # Again, foo not updated
>>> foo
['one', 2, 3, 4]
```

Why isn't foo updated after `foo[:][1] = 'two'`?

**Update:** Maybe I didn't explain my questions clearly. I know when slicing, a new list is created. My doubt is why a slicing assignment updates the list (e.g. `foo[:1] = ['one']`), but if there are two levels of slicing, it doesn't update the original list (e.g. `foo[:][2:] = ['three', 'four']`).

Comment: Have you used `numpy` in the past, perhaps? Numpy arrays use slicing differently from Python lists.

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue

Comment: congratulations! you have discovered [how to clone or copy a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/3904031)! next ask [how deep did the copy go?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26562235/3904031)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because python does **not** have *l*-values that could be assigned. Instead, some expressions have an assignment form, which is different.

A `foo[something]` is a syntactic sugar for:

```
foo.__getitem__(something)
```

but a `foo[something] = bar` is a syntactic sugar for rather different:

```
foo.__setitem__(something, bar)
```

Where a slice is just a special case of `something`, so that `foo[x:y]` expands to

```
foo.__getitem__(slice(x, y, None))
```

and `foo[x:y] = bar` expands to

```
foo.__setitem__(slice(x, y, None), bar)
```

Now a `__getitem__` with slice returns a new list that is a copy of the specified range, so modifying it does not affect the original array. And assigning works by the virtue of `__setitem__` being a different method, that can simply do something else.

However the special assignment treatment applies only to the outermost operation. The constituents are normal expressions. So when you write

```
foo[:][1] = 'two'
```

it gets expanded to

```
foo.__getitem__(slice(None, None, None)).__setitem__(1, 'two')
```

the `foo.__getitem__(slice(None, None, None))` part creates a copy and that copy is modified by the `__setitem__`. But not the original array.

Comment: but why partial slicing, say, foo[:1]=['one'], works?

Comment: **Any slicing** does. It is _double_ slicing that doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/3099185

probably this could also help .....

Answer (score 20):

`foo[:]` is a copy of `foo`. You mutated the copy.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue is worth adding here, `foo[:]` may look the same, but it's an lvalue in `foo[:] = ...` and an rvalue in `foo[:]  [2:] = ...`

Comment: @qarma, it is incorrect to speak of lvalues and rvalues in Python. It does not have them. In python `[]=` is simply a different operator from `[]`.

Comment: Yes that's correct, please provide an explanation in the answer for the rest to see.

Comment: @qarma: I think you're confusing two different people. Jan Hudec's answer already explains all of that.

Comment: But that's not what you're doing with `foo[:][1] = 'two'`, so it isn't the case.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 see I understand your answer exactly, but not everyone does. Shall I expand your answer?

Comment: @qarma - If you have a substantial contribution to make, why not create your own answer? No need to put my name on your efforts/ideas. :)

Answer (score 13):

The main thing to notice here is that `foo[:]` will return a copy of itself and then the indexing `[1]` will be applied *on the copied list that was returned*

```
# indexing is applied on copied list
(foo[:])[1] = 'two'
    ^
copied list
```

You can view this if you retain a reference to the copied list. So, the `foo[:][1] = 'two'` operation can be re-written as:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# the following is similar to foo[:][1] = 'two'

copy_foo = foo[:]  
copy_foo[1] = 'two'
```

Now, `copy_foo` has been altered:

```
print(copy_foo)
# [1, 'two', 3, 4]
```

But, `foo` remains the same:

```
print(foo)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In your case, *you didn't name the intermediate result* from copying the `foo` list with `foo[:]`, that is, you didn't keep a reference to it. After the assignment to `'two'` is perfomed with `foo[:][1] = 'two'`, *the intermediate copied list ceases to exist*.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
foo[1]  = 'two'
```

and

```
foo[2:] = ['three', 'four']
```

and it works.

The answer why is in the comment above (because you're using a copy)